# WPF application pages settings properties on outer window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm building an application in WPF. The interface is structured somewhat like Microsoft's [Zune software](http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/software). There will be a menu at the top; each menu item will correspond to a page, and each page will have a submenu and whatever controls it needs. However, I want the menu, the submenu, and the background color to be declared on the window, but have the colors of those elements specified by each page.

What's the best way to have each page specify properties about the window that contains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a different resource dictionary for each page with the colors/styles for that page.  Then at the top of each page, reference the appropriate resource dictionary.